# Wheelnav.js donut menu clockwise rotation only

Tags: jquery, wheelnav.js

I have created a wheelnav.js navigation menu. I need to fix the rotation of the menu to clockwise only. Currently the rotation is both clockwise and anti clock wise. I have looked in the documentation of wheelnav.js but couldn't seem to find any options which set that property. Need help in fixing the rotation to clockwise only.

Current work so far : http://www.betatesting87.com/wheel/

Answer (score 1):

Need to Introduce `rotateRound` attribute

```js
var piemenu = new wheelnav('piemenu');
piemenu.clockwise = false; //for counter clockwise get it true
piemenu.rotateRound = true;

piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 1.09;
piemenu.animatetime = 1100;
piemenu.animateeffect = 'linear';
piemenu.selectedPercent = 1.1;
piemenu.createWheel();
```

```css
#piemenu>svg {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

#piemenu {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #piemenu {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-0] {
  fill: #56C5D0;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-0] {
  fill: #876FB2;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-0] {
  fill: #56C5D0;
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0.77;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-1],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-3],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-5],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-7],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-9] {
  fill: #336C8C;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-1],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-3],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-5],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-7],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-9] {
  fill: #876FB2;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-1],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-3],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-5],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-7],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-9] {
  fill: #336C8C;
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0.77;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-2],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-4],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-6],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-8],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic-10] {
  fill: #56C5D0;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-2],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-4],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-6],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-8],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected-10] {
  fill: #876FB2;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-2],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-4],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-6],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-8],
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover-10] {
  fill: #56C5D0;
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0.77;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-basic] {
  fill: #333;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-selected] {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: none;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-hover] {
  fill: #222;
  stroke: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title]>tspan {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wheelnav@1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.min.js"></script>
<div id='piemenu' data-wheelnav data-wheelnav-slicepath='DonutSlice' data-wheelnav-colors='#E34C26,#F06529' data-wheelnav-navangle='315' data-wheelnav-cssmode data-wheelnav-init>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Apply'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Survey Preparation'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Technical Review'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Final Submission of SAT'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Survey'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Factual Accuracy Review'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Validation Review'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Award Decision'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Continuous Assessment'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='Re-Accreditation'></div>
</div>
```